# Force redirection with https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, https

I am redirecting my page from HTTP to HTTPS but it does not work at all, my page is wordpress, and I have SSL certificate from digital ocean with lets encrypt, These are my cases

```
WORKS
http://mipagina.com -> https://mipagina.com

IT DOES NOT WORK
http://www.mipagina.com -> https://mipagina.com
```

this is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 
[R=301,L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/redirect-www-to-non-www-https

Comment: Keep in mind that "mipagina.com" and "www.mipagina.com" are completely separate hosts from the http server's point of view. Make sure they are served by the same virtual host, so that the same rules get applied...